# In liferay portal how to restrict multisession to base session mode?

Tags: java, security, session, liferay, portlet

In liferay portal, by default, is enabled multi-session mode, how to change to use base-session mode?

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what you mean by multisession and base session mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the following values in portal-ext.properties

```
live.users.enabled=true
#
# Set the following to true if users are allowed to have simultaneous logins
# from different sessions. This property is not used unless the property
# "live.users.enabled" is set to true.
#
auth.simultaneous.logins=false
```